# How do I edit an interactive PDF?

Tags: pdf, adobe, acrobat, acrobat-sdk

We have a form that needs to be filled in an interactive PDF Form. Details like Name, Amount of different expenses are to be filled is there a way to open the source code in a simplified manner so that I can use Excel VBA macros to edit the data for the PDF.

The thing is that we already have the data to entered to PDF in Excel format. So if I am able to open the pdf in a text file or something I can easily alter the data for PDF using the Excel, even copy-paste is not gonna ease my work.

Here is the link to the PDF form that I need to open in a readable text manner
http://www.mca.gov.in/MCA21/dca/downloadeforms/eformTemplates/NCA/Form_ADT-2.zip

Please get me a way that I can use any software to edit such Form type PDFs.

What I have tried:

I have tried opening the PDF using Hexeditor but that thing is so binary and I am not able to get things connected with that.

Comment: It's going to be difficult to do this using a text editor of any kind. You're going to need a PDF library tool to parse the PDF and enum the fields so you can populate their values. My personal suggestion is PDFBox but you'll need to find one that matches the languages you know and the skill set you have.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to create an FDF file and import that into the blank form.

The easiest way to get an idea how the FDF file looks like, is to fill the form manually, and export the data as FDF.

Then you should be able to recreate that FDF using Excel.

Forget Hex editor or so; unless you really know what you are doing, you will kill off your PDF document,

Comment: I think this thing might work. Thanks for the help!